# How do I check what the admin status is in my telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, botman

I need to write some logic in my bot which checks if a user is admin/owner/creator/member etc

I can see when I look at the user data structure, it has a `status` attribute with, in the case below, the value of 'member'.  How can I check for admin, owner and creator?

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123456789
            [is_bot] => 
            [first_name] => John
            [username] => Doe
            [language_code] => en
        )

    [status] => member
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Botman User Extension class:

```
 The member's status in the chat.
 Can be “creator”, “administrator”, “member”, “restricted”, “left” or “kicked”.
```